# JTextField : How to set text on the left of JTextField when text too long

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a long `String` that I want to display in a `JTextField`. If the `String` is too long, it is showing the right-portion of the `String`, rather than the left portion, even when I use `setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT)`

For example, if my `String` is **"JTextField example , this text is too long"**, it should show as...

```
|----------------------|
| JTextField example ..|
|----------------------|
```

but instead it shows as...

```
|----------------------|
| this text is too long|
|----------------------|
```

Could someone please suggest how this can be fixed.

Comment: You can use `setCaretPosition(0)` to set the position to the left side of the `JTextField` but in order to be able to scroll you are going to have to add the `JTextField` to a `JScrollPane`

Comment: @twain249 : Why not put that, as an answer ? Too good, will work as expected :-)

Comment: @twain249: Even without a `JScrollPane`, `JTextField` can scroll using the left and right arrow keys; `setScrollOffset()` looks promising, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the horizontalAlignement works fine when the size of the field is bigger than the number of chars of the string, but if it is smaller it only does the LEFT_ALIGNMENT with the setText of its creation, not with any later setText.

You could force the position of the caret to the begining of the text using:

```
myTextField.setCaretPosition(0);
```