# set alignment of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jtextfield

My question is with reference to this post here [JTextField : How to set text on the left of JTextField when text too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309235/jtextfield-how-to-set-text-on-the-left-of-jtextfield-when-text-too-long)

If the string is too long, is there any way to display the text in the next subsequent lines instead of a single line?

Right now, it displays the string as

```
|----------------------|
| JTextField example ..|
|----------------------|
```

Is there any way i can make it like this?

```
|----------------------|
| JTextField example ..|
|..continue string.....|
|.........end of string|
|----------------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a field with several lines you should use a

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea()
```

instead since the `JTextField` does not support it (afaik).

**EDIT**
To get the `JTextArea` to scroll you need to put it in a `JScrollPane` like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Test");
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
//textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: thanks.. but when i use `JTextArea`, do i need to add something extra with it so that it is scroll-able? Right now, it displays only part of the text and is not scroll-able

Comment: Updated my answer with scroll explanation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)  Isn't there any way in which it automatically breaks the long sentence and displays into multiple lines based on the textArea size?

Comment: Updated again, you need to set `textArea.setLineWrap(true)`, the line after is if you want it to wrap whole words instead

Answer (score 0):

Your linked post indicates you simply wish to display a long string. If you don't require editing, I'd suggest using a JLabel and using HTML tags.

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("<html>I will wrap.</html>");
```